# how to run power shell script in Azure functions

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I have really simple PowerShell script, this script meant to go to ADLS Gen 2 Container and rename files and replace some characters in those files *.txt files below, is my power shell code and my function screen shot in Portal, how do I run this in this script in Azure function?

Some of the basics step I have to do

```
//rename files in ADLS Gen2 Inbound Container 
 Get-ChildItem 'Inbound/BOB/2021/09/*.txt' | rename-item -NewName {$_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-16) + $_.Extension -replace "_"," "}
 Get-ChildItem 'Inbound/BOB/2021/09/*.txt' | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(8) }

 ///Change double Pipe delimiter to single inside the files
 $Content.replace('||','|')|Set-Content Inbound/BOB/2021/09/*.txt
 $Content.replace('||','|')|Set-Content Inbound/BOB/2021/09/*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [quick start guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-powershell) would be a good first step. You will need to decide how you want your script to be started, where it is going to get input data, and where it is going to put output data (see [Triggers and bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings)). See [Azure Functions PowerShell developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell) for further details.