# Run PowerShell Script from Office Scripts (Excel Online)

Tags: node.js, powershell, office-scripts

I am wondering if it is possible to run a PowerShell script from within an Office Script. My goal is to call the Office Script from PowerAutomate, then have the Office Script kick off a PowerShell process that performs some other automated tasks. This is the code I have so far and I am getting the error "See line 3, column 5:Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable."

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('powershell.exe', ['C:/Users/utrl/PythonWatcher.ps1']);
child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('DATA:', data.toString());
});
child.stdout.on('close', function(data){
    console.log('psscript closed');
});
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here, or an easier way to accomplish what I am trying to do in Office Scripts? For further context, I want the PS to kick off as a result of the PowerAutomate flow. The company I work at does not have PowerAutomate desktop (which I know has way more flexibility to kick off code). I also do not want to use task scheduler to kick off the PS as my company does not allow task scheduler to run when users are not logged in, and I need this process to run regardless of if a user is logged in. So I am working with some constraints here.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Office Scripts make updates to Excel workbooks. They are scoped to one workbook but can connect to other services and other workbooks via Power Automate. You may want to look into power shell and azure functions interoperability. [Here's a post from a couple months ago that may have leads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037101/how-to-run-power-shell-script-in-azure-functions).